Multiplayer one-round one-move voronoi game on graphs
I'm trying to solve a variant of Voronoi Game.
Given a Graph $G=(V, E)$, with uniform distance $d(E)=1$, a subset of the vertices $\hat{V} \subseteq V$ are vertices of interests. $k$ players take turns to place their facilities $V^*_i$ on graph $G$. We define a subgraph $G_i = \{ V_i, E : \forall V_i, d(V_i, V^*_i) \leq d(V_i, V^*_j) \}$, that is in plain words, every vertex in the subgraph is closer to the player $i$'s facility than other facilities.
Each player will take turns to place their facilities. Each player will place at most 1 facility. The goal for player $i$ is to maximize the verticies of interest in his subgraph, or $|\hat{V}| \in G_i$.
My research points me to several papers, such as Nash equilibria in Voronoi games on graphs, but most of them simply states that the problem is NP-hard. Also, I am not even sure if I need Nash equilibrium, since I am just trying to find the optimal placement for each player.
As this is a practical problem, and the space is small, think $k=5$, $|V|=25$, I'm wondering if there are any greedy, approximation, randomized algorithms that are efficient for this task?
I would also appreciate any hints, or places to further my search.
